# Failed to move File

Tags: java, file, move

I have a small issue, I want to move a File with java and tried it like this:

```
try {
    String oFile = frame.selectedFMNGR.getPath() + "\\" + em.getFileName();
    String nFile = Start.safePath + "\\" + em.getFileName();
                       
    System.out.println(oFile);
    System.out.println(nFile);
    File afile =new File(oFile);
              
    if(afile.renameTo(new File(nFile))){
        System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Moving failed!");
    }
} catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

but my log always returns that it failed:

> C:\mails\B_Testmail1.eml
>
> C:\Safe\B_Testmail1.eml
>
> Moving failed!

What is wrong here?

Edit: I do not want to use external libraries like apache commons. I know it would be a lot easier.

Comment: Does the target file already exist? Did you write the file without closing it? The rename will fail on Windows in both cases.

Comment: Have you checked that the file does not already exist in the new path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with java.nio.file; at least, it it fails you'll know why:

```
final Path src = Paths.get(frame.selectedFMNGR.getPath(), em.getFileName());
final Path dst = Paths.get(Start.safePath, em.getFileName());

Files.move(src, dst);
```

Comment: That helped me. The error actually shows that i have the file still open.

Comment: While you're at it, use the new API everywhere ;) You won't get back to `File` anytime soon

Comment: I will look at it. Im actually new to Java, forgot on a bufferedreader the close. The main issue when you work since years with c++ and raii \ :D /

Comment: Don't forget to use try-with-resources as well

Answer (score 0):

There is no error or exception in your code.

Make sure there is a file in source directory which do you want to move from one location to another location. i.e.

```
C:\mails\B_Testmail1.eml
```